# Is it possible to record a call in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I want to record calls in iPhone.In android there are listeners for that by using them we can record the call.Is there listeners in iphone to get notification of dialed and incoming call and record those call?I have searched in iTunes store and came to know that some applications are there which can record calls. So can we record the calls in iphone?

Comment: I can't speak to iOS features directly, but Google Voice should be able to do it (press 4 during a call.) Note: I haven't specifically verified on iOS but the call recording is a feature of the remote service and not a feature of the phone -- so it should work identically on Android and iOS. (I think?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, It's not possible. Plus, it's illegal in the US ([In some states and without prior notification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_recording_laws#United_States)), as some support services (XBOX Live for example) must notify the caller that they will be recorded.

Comment: it not illegal if we notify is it... or is it. any how the answer hard no.... until you make the user your VOIP application and you provide some kind of proxy which you can tap into if needed.

Comment: then in itunes store there are some application....how they are doing recording..do you have any idea?

Comment: @medampudi I edited my answer after checking on Wikipedia.

Comment: Stark Can you provide a link to one of these application ? and for your second question, check @medampudi's comment.

Comment: @ Nacereddine....http://callrec.me/ this is the application's url....which can record the call....

Comment: first off i have not used many... and my search on itunes is limited... can you please point me to them... a couple for example.. and coming to the recording part as i told you can put in your own VoIP code,,,, make the user use your interface to make calls and record the calls. of course it becomes the users responsibility to notify the other side ;)...  http://recordertheapp.com/screencast/ uses this method i think.. need to check it out... but hey i am not in the US..

Comment: stark.... that is a webserice that it uses.. an external telephone or something right... is that the case.,

Comment: As @medampudi said, it's using a VoIP service (when available) or routing the call through their own "[access-number](http://callrec.me/access-number)" like a proxy (sort of). Then you'll add the number you wanted to call in the first place to the conversation (conference call)

Comment: yup.... that is what i thought so my idea of having a proxy still holds good,,, any how... i have not worked on it in detail... if you need i can search for a more concise answer.

Comment: thanx everyone....for providing me guidance.....

Comment: There are legal issues with this, so most companies don't allow it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_recording_laws . On Android, it's available on some cases, but the API isn't working on many devices, or require special tweaking that are extremely hard to find, or need root. On some cases even root can't help. This app tries a lot to work on most devices: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.boldbeast.recorder&hl=en . I have no idea how it does so much