# record audio in the iphone/ipad speaker

Tags: ios, audio, record, speaker

I would like to know if it exist a solution to record audio which is in the speaker of iphone/iPad.

I try to make an application which is able to record audio during a conversation.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to record a call in iphone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168735/is-it-possible-to-record-a-call-in-iphone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two reasons why it isn't possible or practical to create an application to do this.

#1) Apple **will not** approve applications that can infringe on customers privacy rights.  If you can record a conversation, that can be a privacy issue or it can be illegal.

#2) While a call is going on (or, at least at the beginning, until you switch out of it), you can't have another application in the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.recordertheapp.com/

(First google search result from: record audio in iphone)

Comment: Nice find, and interesting that they have to use a (paid) service through a non-Apple provider to record the outgoing calls... good workaround on their part. The original poster seemed to be asking for a way to create (or "make") an app to record conversations.

Comment: It was less about directly answering the question than showing the lack of preparation in asking. I noticed the limitation as well, but you could record incoming calls through Google Voice.